# ElasticSearch instance not reachable from outside the server - Azure Windows 2012

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, windows-server-2012-r2

I have set up Elastic Search 2.3.0 as a service in an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 R2. I can access elastic search instance from within the server using

```
http://localhost:9200
```

but I cannot access from outside the server.

What have I tried?

- Just for testing I have made the VM available outside the virtual network.
- Opened up the port 9200 in Windows Firewall settings as an Inbound Traffic rule
- Added an endpoint in Azure portal settings opening up port 9200

Tried this with VM Classic as well.

Also for testing whether the VM is alright, I had set up IIS in that machine, opened up the port 80. The default IIS page is accessible from outside.

Only thing I have not tried is setting ES in a Linux VM.

I can't find anything in the elasticsearch logs. On the browser (Chrome), there are no logs in the Network. It just spins, waiting for the server, and snaps with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".

Can anybody that had done this shed some light please?

UPDATE:
Here is what I can see in netstat:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:9200         machine-name:0       LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:9300         machine-name:0       LISTENING
```

Comment: In some other instance, our team uses ES1.7.0, which works completely fine. Puzzled.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Starting with ES 2.0, the elasticsearch process only [binds to localhost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_network_changes.html#_bind_to_localhost), which explains why you can query ES from inside but not from the outside.

You need to change the following setting in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Remember trying this too @Val. Added `network.host: A.B.C.D`, restarted the service. Still no luck. And its not reachable with localhost either. Also tried `network.host: ["A.B.C.D", "127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]`. No luck with that either.

Comment: In this case, the entries are lost from netstat for ports 9200 and 9300.

Comment: You need to use a real IP address, `A.B.C.D` is just an example, but it needs to be something like : 123.123.123.123

Comment: Please try with the value 0.

Comment: Thnx @Val, but no luck with that. For your initial post, I see this in the error log: `Exception in thread "main" BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]
; nested: ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /<ip-address>:9400]; nested: Bind
Exception[Cannot assign requested address: bind];`

Comment: Hang on.. I did something wrong.. I tried with `network.host: 0.0.0.0` and it works splendidly well..

Comment: Can you update your post with value 0 please, so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108172/discussion-between-droidbot-and-val).

Comment: network.host: 0.0.0.0 worked for me. I also restarted the service. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same case.   Looking in the log

```
tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/NODE.log
```

I saw this:

```
 [NODE_NAME] publish_address {10.XXX.XXX.XXX:9300}, bound_addresses {10.XXX.XXX.XXX:9300}
 [NODE_NAME] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
 [NODE_NAME] node validation exception
 [1] bootstrap checks failed
 [1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
 [NODE_NAME] stopping ...
 [NODE_NAME] stopped
```

**Solution:**

Modify the archive /`etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` in the line discorvery seed with this:

```
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
```

Done.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to set the network.host to special values

eg.

```
network.host: [_local_, _site_]
```

This works for me.

Comment: I may be an ElasticSearch noob @Amey, sorry. Can you explain it a bit further please. For example, what do you mean by 'special values'?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html. This is the reference link for this.
_local_ Any loopback addresses on the system, for example 127.0.0.1.

_site_ Any site-local addresses on the system, for example 192.168.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Please note that for me success was achieved only after setting

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

instead of

```
http.host: "localhost"
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved for me on Windows server 2012 with Elasticsearch 7.1.1 adding in C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\config\elasticsearch.yml the following config:

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```