# How to Access ElasticSearch From Server?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

I am using elastic search in my ubuntu16.04 server. When i am trying to access elasticsearch from browser by using url ip:port/_cat/indices?v. I am getting **site can't be reached**. After that i am change the network.host value to network.host: 0.0.0.0. After change the network.host ip the search engine not started. How can i access the elasticsearch in my browser.I changed the port also.

Thank you..

Comment: Check the elastic startup logs to know on what port the elastic is running. Try connecting from the same machine browser first. If that works, then a problem of not able to connect from other machine is related to route/publicip configuration.

Comment: check port is open or not e.g 9200 for es or 5601 for kibana?

Comment: i am not using kibana

Comment: I am getting this errors when running es [1]: max file descriptors [10240] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for ES not being reachable. I would start with the obvious and make sure that:

1. ES is listening on the port: on the ES instance when you run 'curl
   ip:port' you should get an answer. if not the service didn't start
   well.
2. make sure there are no firewall rules/security groups that prevent
   access from remote network.
3. make sure network.publish_host is configure correctly:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings

more info here: [ElasticSearch instance not reachable from outside the server - Azure Windows 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397922/elasticsearch-instance-not-reachable-from-outside-the-server-azure-windows-201)